# PHP sending just one blank space on mail

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html form and I'm sending it through a PHP mail.
All fields seem to work perfect but one!

The thing is, I fill out that one text field from a button in my html and using a short javascript function. do you think that's in any way interfering with the php code? The text field I'm having problems with is:

`input type="text" name="txtnomtour" id="txtnomtour"`

Tank you for your HELP!

here is my work:

```js
function showcap(nom,tour) {
 var nombretour1 = tour;
 var div = document.getElementById(nom);
 div.style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById('txtnomtour').value = String(nombretour1);
}
```

```css
#btnenviar{
 border:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 border-color:#6C0;
 background-color:#91B31A;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
 color:#fff;
}

#btnenviar:hover{
 background-color:#829A1F;
}

.botonredondo{
 transform: translateX(30%);
 background-color:#690;
 background: linear-gradient(#F00,#900);
 border-radius:20px;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#FFF;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 width:55%;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 border-color:#F00;
}

.botonredondo:hover{
 background-color:#6C0;
 background: linear-gradient(#C30, #F60);
 color:#FC0;
}
```

```html
<form name="frmcontacto" id="frmcontacto" method="post" action="enviar_mailreserva.php">
<table>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="6">
         <input type="text" input name="txtnomtour" id="txtnomtour" disabled="disabled" style="background-color:transparent; border:hidden; font-size:30px;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333">Fecha del tour:</font>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
         <input type="text" name="txtfecha" id="txtfecha" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333">Adultos</font>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="number" name="txtadultos" id="txtadultos" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; width:40px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;" min="2" max="15">
        </td>
        <td>
         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333">Niños (Menores de 12 años):</font>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="number" name="txtninos" id="txtninos" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; width:40px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;" min="1" max="15">
        </td>
        <td>
         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333">Lugar y Hora de salida:</font>
        </td>
        <td>
         <select name="txtpickup" id="txtpickup" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
 <option value="1">Hotel Country Inn & Suites Aeropuerto</option>
      </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
         Nombre Contacto:
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
         <input type="text" name="txtnombre" id="txtnombre" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; width:625px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
         E-Mail:
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
         <input type="text" name="txtmail" id="txtmail" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; width:625px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333">Teléfono:</font>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="txtareatel" id="txtareatel" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; width:40px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="txtnumtel" id="txtnumtel" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
        </td>
        <td>
         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333">Móbil:</font>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="txtareacel" id="txtareacel" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; width:40px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="txtnumcel" id="txtnumcel" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:30px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333">Comentarios:</font>
        </td>
     <td colspan="5">
      <textarea name="txtcoment" id="txtcoment" cols="47" rows="5" style="border:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); height:100px; width:400px; padding-left:10px; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;"></textarea>
        </td>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="6">
         <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="btnenviar" id="btnenviar" value="Enviar"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<!--This is the button-->
<table>
           <tr>
             <td>
                 <img src="../images/booking_icon.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
                <td valign="middle"><a onclick="showcap('formbooking', 'Aguas Termales Baldí')" class="botonredondo">Reserve Aquí</a></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add your php code as well

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH problem solved I just had to change the disabled property to readonly!

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have provided:

1. I don't seem to see the element with `id="formbooking"`. Hence, I am not sure what's the purpose of the js code that involves this element id.
2. It seems that the javascript is only run when user clicks on the button. There is a possibility that user might just press enter in one of the form fields and causes the form to be submitted.
3. The input field `txtnomtour` seems to have `disabled="disabled"` attribute in it. Disabled input field value does not get posted when a form is submitted.

**To achieve the behavior that you have desired, you might need to remove the `disabled="disabled"` from the `txtnomtour` input field.**

On another note, some improvements on the code would be to replace the following HTML tag:

```
<a onclick="showcap('formbooking', 'Aguas Termales Baldí')" class="botonredondo">Reserve Aquí</a>
```

with a normal submit button:

```
<button type="submit">Reserve Aqui</button>
```

This will allow the form to be processed via the same logic flow. Hence, when user clicks the button or presses enter on the input field, it will run the javascript.

Then, in your form tag, you might need to include the following:

```
<form name="frmcontacto" id="frmcontacto" method="post" action="enviar_mailreserva.php" onsubmit="return showcap('formbooking', 'Aguas Termales Baldí');">
```

This will cause the form to run the javascript code in the `onsubmit` before processing it further.

Then, in your js file, replace the following:

```
function showcap(nom,tour) {
    // what this is for?
    var nombretour1 = tour;
    var div = document.getElementById(nom);
    div.style.display = "block";
    // this will update the txtnomtour value
    document.getElementById('txtnomtour').value = nombretour1;
    return true; // this basically tells the form to continue to submit
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH problem solved I just had to change the disabled property to read only!

Comment: @jonsm Glad that I can help. Can you mark it as the answer?